# Change static Eloquent property in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am wanting to change a static property that is set in the Database/Eloquent/Model.php file. What would be the best way to change the value from within the /app directory? The problem with making the change in that file is that updating composer could possibly overwrite it.

Here is the property:

```
public static $snakeAttributes = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply redefine it in your model?

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to do this as all Laravel's build in using a camelCase naming.

Have a look also to the new [Helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings) section... You will find out some useful functions which help you create camelCase and snake_case names.

Comment: You made a confusion, here we are changing from the default snake_case to camelCase. This flag affects the result of the `toArray()` method. Note this is not related to Laravel naming convention nor PSR, but rather to database field names. To sum it up, you may want to read these messages by Taylor: [(1)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/334#issuecomment-13670797), [(2)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/391#issuecomment-13844569)